# Symfony few services but one database

Tags: postgresql, symfony

Trying to host my symfony web services on render.com but with free tier I can only create one pgsql DB. I want this database to be used by multiple services is it possible? What I tried to do was to connect my services to database and make migrations but when I migrate data from one service, tables from other services are droped. Is there way to make many services use one database?

Comment: See if your database migration system supports some kind of prefix for its own tablenames.

Comment: You could make one service responsible for migrations (write) and use the rest of the service only read, as an api only. I am not sure if this would be working for your case. If all services are not related to each other, than a prefix to your table should suffice.

Comment: Something like this? https://medium.com/@kcmueller/symfony-how-to-add-table-prefixes-with-doctrine-c7feff6ab95  Anyway, in general this doesn't look like good idea and each app should have a separate database. From multiple reasons (security, backups, ...)